# Codeigniter 4 - using callbacks in model

Tags: codeigniter-4

Let's say I have a table called 'projects'. One of the columns contains a filename string.
What i'd like to do, is to delete the file after/before deleting the row from the database. I see, that Codeigniter 4's models can now use a callback function. But i don't know how can I access data, particularly the filename field.

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class ProjectModel extends Model {

    protected $table      = 'projects';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $returnType     = 'App\Entities\Project';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = false;

    protected $allowedFields = ['id', 'title', 'desc', 'filename'];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';

    protected $afterDelete = ['deleteFiles'];

    protected function deleteFiles() {
        // here i would like to delete the file
    }


}
```

Or am I approaching this the wrong way? Should I just get the data in my Controller, delete the file and then delete the row from database? I would do that in CI3 this way, but now i discovered the callbacks in CI4 and I consider this a more elegant way/better practice.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

So later I found out, that a better idea is to use the beforeDelete method. But I'm unable to access the current row. If I use the delete method this way:

`$this->projectsModel->delete(3);`

I can access the Id:

```
protected $beforeDelete = ['deleteFiles'];

protected function deleteImages($data) {
    $id = $data['id'][0];
}
```

But when I try to delete more rows at once:
`$this->projectModel->where('some_prop', 'XY')->delete();`
$data passed to the beforeDelete function is equal to NULL

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to counter this problem. 
The first way is to follow a repository pattern for CRUD operations. Since the data has to be there in the row, you will need to first chain the find function and then the delete method.

Another way is to override the delete function in the subclass. afterDelete trigger expects four parameters : id, purge, result, data. Since this is a delete operation: the result will be boolean and data will be null since data doesn't exist. So what you can do is you can override the delete function to fetch the data before it calls afterDelete trigger and pass it to the function you are using as afterDelete.